# nvcc: get device compute capability in runtime

Tags: cuda, nvidia, nvcc

I have an application that uses the GPU and that runs on different machines. I currently manually specify to NVCC the parameters `-arch=compute_xx -code=sm_xx`, according to the GPU model installed on the machine I am running on.

I want to write an automation that will be able to extract those values from the host machine, so that I will not need to specify them manually. Is there a way to really do that automatically?

Comment: You can compile code for every GPU you will run on into a single executable. I see no use case for this

Comment: This is a docker that is getting built automatically, each time on a different machine. This is the use case. And currently I have to specify these values manually each time, after checking some table in wikipedia

Comment: No you don't understand. You can specify every architecture at once and then it doesn't matter

Comment: Otherwise run nvidia-smi, grep and build a table somewhere

Comment: oh :) :) I did not know that.  I did not understand at first that you mean that I can build them all at once

Comment: @talonmies, there might be use-case where you want totally different kernels / kernel call sequence depending on the compute capability. Getting that information at runtime has applications.

Comment: @FlorentDUGUET: Indeed, and that is what the driver API PTX JIT and runtime linakge facilities are for. But that isn't what this question is about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the C++ CUDA runtime API, you can do as follows to find the major and minor CUDA compute capability version:

```
cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, dev);
std::printf("%d.%d\n", deviceProp.major, deviceProp.minor);
```

This will print, for example "6.1" on a Pascal card.

If you have the CUDA demo suite in your installation, in the `extras/demo_suite` directory, the `deviceQuery` executable in there uses this API to fetch the compute capability version:

```
$ /path/to/cuda/extras/demo_suite/deviceQuery | grep 'CUDA Capability'
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    6.1
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    6.1
```

However, when building CUDA programs intended to work on a number of possible GPUs, the best way of handling this is by building in the PTX / binary device code for each architecture / compute capability you want like so:

```
nvcc x.cu \
    --generate-code arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
    --generate-code arch=compute_50,code=sm_52 \
    --generate-code arch=compute_53,code=sm_53
```

This is further described in the [NVCC docs](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#extended-notation).  Also note that adding an entry with `code=compute_XX` as well as `code=sm_XX` will include the portable PTX code for the device code in your program and will enable JIT compilation and support for newer architectures you haven't explicitly included in your compilation.  You may find that all you need is something like `-arch=compute_50 -code=compute_50` to work with all Maxwell cards and newer, but without necessarily the best code for some newer GPUs.

Comment: Do you say that I can actually specify multiple architectures to nvcc?

Comment: @SomethingSomething Yes.  Only the appropriate code for your current GPU gets run / JIT-compiled.  The code is built into your binary for all the architectures you specify.

Comment: @SomethingSomething: Yes. As I did. Twice

Comment: But someone else explained.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get compute capability in command line then you can use the following snippet:

`export ARCH="$(nvidia-smi --query-gpu=compute_cap --format=csv,noheader|head -n 1)"`